# Fatal error: Call to undefined method in view

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Have an error in view when I try to get results from JoinColumns. Here is a query in controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $users = $this->getEntityManager()
                     ->getRepository('\ApanelUsers\Entity\Usercommon')
                     ->findAll();

    $viewModel = new ViewModel(['users' => $users]);
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Here is a part of Entity code

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="UserId", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $userid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="UserEmail", type="string", length=100, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $useremail;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="UserFirstName", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $userfirstname;

/**
 * @var \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_StatusId", referencedColumnName="UserStatusId", nullable=false)
 * })
 */
private $userStatusid;
```

This is my view

```
<td>
        <?= $user->getUserFirstName(); ?> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $user->getUserEmail(); ?>
    </td>
```

When I try to get `<?= $user->getUser_StatusId(); ?>` I've got an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ApanelUsers\Entity\Usercommon::getUser_StatusId() in /home/xtadmin/localhost/panorama-hotel.local/www/module/ApanelUsers/view/apanel-users/index/index.phtml on line 52

--| UPDATE |--
I have changed Entity files on generated by Doctrine, so I have:
Entity

```
 /**
 * @var \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_StatusId", referencedColumnName="UserStatusId", nullable=false)
 * })
 */
private $userStatusid;

 /**
 * Set userStatusid
 *
 * @param \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus $userStatusid
 * @return Usercommon
 */
public function setUserStatusid(\ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus $userStatusid = null)
{
    $this->userStatusid = $userStatusid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userStatusid
 *
 * @return \ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus 
 */
public function getUserStatusid()
{
    return $this->userStatusid;
}
```

index.phtml

```
<?= $user->getUserStatusid(); ?>
```

And I steel have an error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DoctrineORMModule\Proxy__CG__\ApanelUsers\Entity\Userstatus could not be converted to string in /home/xtadmin/localhost/panorama-hotel.local/www/module/ApanelUsers/view/apanel-users/index/index.phtml on line 27

Comment: Stupid question, but as you ommited all methods from the entity class - does the method actually exist on the entity class? Maybe you could post the entire class with method signatures?

Comment: Cant understand you. May be question is really stupid, but I'm newby in ZF2 and Doctrine and I need help

Comment: I have correct results from <?= $user->getUserFirstName(); ?> and <?= $user->getUserEmail(); ?>... problem when  I try <?= $user->getUser_StatusId(); ?>

Comment: Have you defined a method  called `getUser_StatusId()` in your `Usercommon` entity ?

Comment: blackbishop - Yes I have `public function getUserStatusId() { return $this->UserStatusId; }
    public function setUserStatusId($UserStatusId) { $this->UserStatusId = $UserStatusId; }`

Comment: 1) So why are your calling it by : `$user->getUser_StatusId();` ? It should be : `getUserStatusId()` 2) It will return an object of type `Userstatus`

Comment: I have change the name - the same error. I have change Entity files on generated by Doctrine, but mistake have not gone (((

Comment: I've wrote on my last comment that _It will return an object of type Userstatus_ !! The error you're getting is self explanatory, the method `getUserStatusId()` returns an object not a string. You should use the method defined in the `Userstatus` to get the `statusId`. Use this and it will work : `getUserStatusId()->getStatusId()` where `getStatusId` is defined in your `Userstatus` entity.

Comment: blackbishop >>> How can I do that? How can I use method defined in the Userstatus? Can you give me code example? I'm really newby ((( . Here is my Skype :: XTishka , If you want you can contact to me by skype, I need help. And... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling a method "getUser_StatusId()" with this underscore but it was defined without it "getUserStatusId()"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but problem have not gone away. Please, look update